# Select dropdown item by vba. Cannot access Iframe.

Tags: asp.net, excel, internet-explorer-8, browser-automation, vba

I want to select drop down item through Excel macro. I cannot refer to the dropdown element by tag name "ddWareHouse" I get error.

I think I am really close with attached code. But I this time I get error Run-time Error (70). Permission denied

```
Sub test3()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim test As HTMLIFrame
Dim BaseURL As String
BaseURL="https://some_adress_which_I_cannot_display_because_because.aspx"
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate BaseURL
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Webpage is loading please wait"
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = IE.document
Set test = html.getElementById("alexIFRAME")
IE.Navigate2 test.src
test.document.getElementById("ddWarehouse").Value = "Lund"
'HERE I GET PERMISSION DENIED ERROR 
End Sub
```

Could you please help me understand how to access the "ddWarehouse" dropdown menu. I attached .jpg file with html code and another .jpg showing how the dropdown menu looks like. Thank you in advance for your support and guidance!!

[image: Dropdown menu]

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up2EW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if `.document` is how you can refer to it there.  What happens when you try something like this on that line,
`html.getElementById('alexIFRAME').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ddWarehouse').Value = "Lund"`

or this element may need accessed differently,
`html.getElementById('alexIFRAME').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ddWarehouse').FindByValue("Lund").Selected = true`

Comment: Your first solution solved the problem. I just had to change "Lund" to "LUN" because in html code it is stated like this:     <option value="LUN">Lund</option>